# Spring DelegatingFilterProxy multi-threading concerns

Tags: multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

While hunting down bugs I came across the Spring 3.0.5 source code `DelegatingFilterProxy` and I wonder whether it bears a performance bottleneck or not.

Given that per web app there is only one instance of DelegatingFilterProxy (per `<filter>` declaration, of course ) I have to assume that under high load a lot of worker threads are trying to call the `doFilter()` method in parallel.

Now have a look at the code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Lazily initialize the delegate if necessary.
    Filter delegateToUse = null;
    synchronized (this.delegateMonitor) {
        if (this.delegate == null) {
            WebApplicationContext wac = findWebApplicationContext();
            if (wac == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?");
            }
            this.delegate = initDelegate(wac);
        }
        delegateToUse = this.delegate;
    }

    // Let the delegate perform the actual doFilter operation.
    invokeDelegate(delegateToUse, request, response, filterChain);
}
```

The `synchronized (this.delegateMonitor)` block must be passed by all threads which means that all workers are forced to queue up patiently until they are allowed to enter.

Regardless of why the bean lookup needed to be done here I suspect that the use of `synchronized`could have been avoided in favour of parallel execution - may be by making `this.delegate` volatile and use synchronization only in case of lookup needs to be done.

So am I barking up the wrong tree ? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - this seems like a potential problem, alghouth (as Ralph noted), it shouldn't be easily noticable. They could have used a double-check locking (with a volatile delegate).

I'd suggest you create an issue in the spring jira. If you don't - I'll do it.

Comment: I have not done that yet. Feel free to do so.  Concerning performance impact I recall my beloved 'Java Concurrency in Practice' book saying that suspending and re-activating threads is huge in clock cycles compared with something like object allocation. Also looking at classes like `AtomicLong` or `ConcurrentHashMap` which avoid synchronized blocks wherever possible is giving me the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it looks like some initialization code. After the first run `this.delegate` has a value different from `null`. Then there is only the are only two statments `if (this.delegate == null)` and `delegateToUse = this.delegate` left in the syncronized blog.

This block is executed once per request, so: NO it does not influent the performance of a web application that can be measured.

*Of course Bozho is right, it can be done better. But you will never notice the difference in performance -- If there would be enough load at the server so that this sycronized block would have a measurabel impact, then everyting else on this server is already completely overloaded*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding load we have been lucky to do load testing on Oracles Exadata and there we have seen similar code becoming a real bottleneck. So I took away for myself to avoid synchronized blocks wherever there is the chance that more than a few threads would access it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with double checking in Spring 4

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Lazily initialize the delegate if necessary.
    Filter delegateToUse = this.delegate;
    if (delegateToUse == null) {
        synchronized (this.delegateMonitor) {
            if (this.delegate == null) {
                WebApplicationContext wac = findWebApplicationContext();
                if (wac == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("No WebApplicationContext found: " +
                            "no ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet registered?");
                }
                this.delegate = initDelegate(wac);
            }
            delegateToUse = this.delegate;
        }
    }

    // Let the delegate perform the actual doFilter operation.
    invokeDelegate(delegateToUse, request, response, filterChain);
}
```

See commit
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c26272cef62b1e6f3bb982d7f71b2f47c685b014

See JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10413